# How do you proceed html markup validation in your svelte app?

Tags: html, svelte, w3c-validation

Is there any efficient way to check entire app(every component and so on) for `html markup` errors?

Comment: Do you really care about strict HTML validity or just want to make sure it compiles?

Comment: Yes, it's only about HTML markup validity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is (easily) possible.

Given that components can be combined in arbitrary an complex ways, including the use of slots, conditionals and dynamic elements (`<svelte:element>`), you would need tooling that tracks everything across components. Most tooling only operates on components in isolation and most people also just don't care much for validity.